# How to solve mat-datepicker-toggle position problem?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, material-design

I've imported material to my Angular 8 project successfully and I'm using bootstrap 
for styling.
I don't plan to use all the material library, only when required. Datepicker from
material is one example I need to use.

I've tried to use the mat-datepicker and encountered problem with the alignment of
the toggle.

here is the template:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="my_date" [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker"
 style="width: 80px;"
 #myDate="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="mydate" id="my_date">                                        
 <mat-datepicker-toggle  matSuffix [for]="myDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>                                                                                
 <mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
```

The toggle is displayed and functioned correctly but it jump to a new line.
I don't wish to use mat form or mat form field cause I'm using boostrap.
Any idea how to align the toggle with the same line of the textbox ?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: The `matSuffix` attribute should only be used if your datepicker toggle is in a `<mat-form-field>` element.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to solve this problem by applying div container for both the input
and the toggle and apply this class:

```
.date_container {        
        float: left;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
```

Comment: this worked like a charm! here is my working code: (my date container was ppm-datepicker-container)

<div class="ppm-datepicker-container">
    <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
    <mat-label>{{labelKey | localize}}:</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="startDp"
           [(ngModel)]="Date"
           (dateChange)="onDateChange($event)"
           [formControl]="DateControl">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle #datepickerToggle matSuffix [for]="startDp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #startDp></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

Comment: I will try this, I hate that ng material did not think this through knowing people would use bootstrap